# How to cache result/layer but run the command anyway in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a very long-running command in my Dockerfile, but if I save the result and run it again it is very fast. So my goal is to run the command and cache at EVERY build so that I am sure I am up-to-date but I also benefit from previous caching.

I have tried the following approach:

```
RUN node ./node_modules/geoip-lite/scripts/updatedb.js
ADD "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=10&format=h" skipcache
RUN node ./node_modules/geoip-lite/scripts/updatedb.js
```

which works at first. But once the database gets updated, the second RUN will takes forever again as the first RUN layer is now outdated and not cached again.

So if I could just specify that the command should always be RUN upon previous cache layer, it will work perfectly.

Thank you

Comment: How would you decide if the command needs to be re-run?  How often does this need to happen?

Comment: I need to run it everytime! but on top of the last cached result

Comment: How do you need to decide if you need to run it (long) from scratch or (short) from the cache?  Is this the same as the Docker layer cache or a different cache?  It sounds like you always want to use the layer cache (fast, because it doesn't run the command) and also always want to run the command (intrinsically slow).

Comment: the updatedb will only take a long time when the cached layer is outdated! So once in a while it will take a long time but that is absolutely needed. And if it caches the result when it takes the long time, then the subsequent build will be very fast. But if I don't run the command I won't know when the db is outdated, and if I don't cache, the build will take forever...